# Does the NSObject init method do anything?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, nsobject

Does it make sense to write `self = [super init];` in a custom initialisation method while subclassing NSObject? I know it's necessary when subclassing any other class, because it might have a custom initialisation, but does the NSObject init method do anything?

Comment: Its a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An object isn’t ready to be used until it has been initialized. The `init` method defined in the `NSObject` class does no initialization; it simply returns self.

So basically you don't necessarily have to call `[super init]` in an `NSObject` subclass, but I still would recommend it. It's simply a better design. If you change the superclass it will still work.

Source: [NSObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init).

Comment: +1 for "I still would recommend it" - the NSObject implementation could change, you could change your class's superclass, etc. It's not your class's job to infer things about its superclass's behavior.

Comment: No, really, your code is **wrong** if you don't `self = [super init...];`.  It doesn't matter what `NSObject`'s implementation does; use the pattern everywhere consistently to minimize fragility and because following the documented correct patterns leads to more maintainable apps.